# Why I am getting max_execution_time error in Word press on local even after increasing execution time?

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp

On increasing the max_execution_time, in the same way Word-Press admin is throwing  error.

Firstly,
I did in php.ini `max_execution_time = 90,` then 120 and then 300 up to 900
In wp-config.php I did  `ini_set('MAX_EXECUTION_TIME', '-1');` in very top of the file.
Also, added $cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0; in config.inc.php.

But my word-press admin is still taking too much time to load and after end throwing error as below:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 900 seconds exceeded in F:\xampp\htdocs\projct\repo1\code\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 2056
There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.
```

- I have tried adding execution time in wp-config.php, .htaccess & in
  php.ini accordingly. Still I am facing same issue.
- I have tried by using latest xampp version and with a old one
  (v3.2.2).

Anyone please guide me with accurate.

Comment: have you checked that your change in `php.ini` really was applied?

Comment: Yes. I am restarting server after saving file.

Comment: Take a look at whats happening in `F:\xampp\htdocs\projct\repo1\code\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 2056`. No website should need that much time, even in an admin area.

Comment: Hi there is just a mysql_query   [ $this->result = mysqli_query( $this->dbh, $query ); ]  ANd its result is   :       mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 2 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 211 [type] => 0 ) here

Comment: When you changed the max exec time, did the error message in the error log change? So you can see that it is really running for 900 seconds or that your change was not made correctly

Comment: Yes for changing time to  120  error message is showing : Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in and same for other.

Answer (score 0):

900 second is too much time to execute something. From your question what I can understand you have problem in your site and you should focus on solving the problem instead of increasing the max execution time.

first open wp-config.php file and paste below code after `<?php` tag to turn on error logging and reporting

```
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);
```

After saving the wp-config.php file try to login admin panel. It will show you the error. You have to solve that error to resolve your loading problem.

Comment: Thank you, But this is not helping me. I am getting no extra error except same (Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in .......).

Comment: The error message indicates it’s a db query - first steps would be to determine what that query is.

Comment: Exactly, you have to find out what is causing such high time. As your error is indicating wp-db.php file it could be database query error. On the other hand it could be coding error too, for example indefinite loop. So, you have to turn on all error reporting, after that you have to solve the error it can be db query or coding error.